# loop with multiple columns in shell

Tags: linux, shell, loops, unix, awk

I have a file with three columns (ID number, x, y)

```
ifile.txt
1      32.2    21.4
4      33.2    43.5
5      21.3    45.6
12     22.3    32.5
32     21.5    56.3
43     33.4    23.4
44     23.3    22.3
55     22.5    32.4
```

I would like use ID numbers as a loop so that is will read like

```
when ID=1, then x=32.2, y=21.4
when ID=4, then x=33.2, y=43.5
and so on
```

I have done as follows, but it seems a lengthy way.

```
id1=1   #ID number
id2=$(wc -l < ifile.txt)   #total number of IDs
while [ $id1 -le $id2 ]
do
ID=$(awk 'NR=='$id1' {print $1}' ifile.txt)
x=$(awk 'NR=='$id1' {print $2}' ifile.txt)
y=$(awk 'NR=='$id1' {print $3}' ifile.txt)
#
#here I want to do some computation using ID, x and y
#e.g. with each ID, I will execute a program by changing its corresponding x and y values
#for instance
echo $ID $x $y
(( id1++ ))
done
```

I need to short it and a convenient way.

Answer (score 3):

This reads each line and does a computation on x and y (you didn't say what computation, so I made one up):

```
$ awk '{printf "ID=%2s: x+y*y=%7.2f\n",$1,$2+$3*$3;}' ifile.txt 
ID= 1: x+y*y= 490.16
ID= 4: x+y*y=1925.45
ID= 5: x+y*y=2100.66
ID=12: x+y*y=1078.55
ID=32: x+y*y=3191.19
ID=43: x+y*y= 580.96
ID=44: x+y*y= 520.59
ID=55: x+y*y=1072.26
```

In other words, `awk` has more better math support than shell.  If you want to do calculations, do it all in awk.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need ID, x and y value separately so that I can use them in my next computation. There are several executations with these values. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @Kayan Why is it that you don't think you can do the computation in awk?

Comment: @Kayan By the way, bash only does _integer_ arithmetic.  Your input numbers are floating point.

Comment: My script is working well. Can I make it more short by using something like `for id in $(cat ifile.txt); do` ...

Comment: @Kayan: no; using `for id in $(cat ifile.txt); do …` will lose all the lines in the input.  What John wrote is better.

Comment: Kayan: Do not use `$(cat ifile.txt)`.  If you must use shell, use the approach in @JonathanLeffler's answer which shows how to use shell to read the file efficiently.  (If you want to do "computations," there is still the issue that `x` and `y` are floating point numbers and the shell cannot handle floating point numbers.)

Answer (score 3):

Superficially, you could use:

```
while read ID x y
do
    case "$ID" in
    …
    esac
    echo "$ID $x $y"
done < ifile.txt
```

where the `case` might, or might not, be an appropriate method for deciding what action to take as a line is read.

I used `read` without the `-r` because the code is going to have heebie-jeebies if the data contains characters (backslashes) that would be affected by the presence or absence of `-r`.  Neither is going to be especially reliable.  You can judge otherwise and use `-r` and thereby satisfy the "thou shalt use `-r`" brigade.

Note that this reads the file once where your code reads the file three times for each line in the file.  That's an O(N<sup>2</sup>) algorithm where an O(N) algorithm is appropriate.

If your computations are complex enough, you'd do better using a more powerful language than the shell.  You could consider `awk` or Perl or Python (or numerous other languages) instead.